# What would be the interior set of an $(n-1)$ dimensional surface in an $n$ dimensional coordinate system?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

i.e set $=$ { $x ∈ R^n  | (c_1\leq x_1\leq d_1, c_2 \leq x_2\leq d_2,...,  x_n=\text{constant}) $}

Comment: This isn't about set theory, so I've removed that tag and replaced it with more appropriate ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonempty interior  implies local dim$=n$ at least at one point. So the interior of the set is empty.